# page intent should happen when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

The problem I am facing over here is whenever I will click on Register button it should redirect me to next page but that not happening over here .when I click on the Register button nothing happens ;it Don't redirect me to next page ..even there is no error ..I too tried various ways out there still its not working. But the thing is I have added validations to my xml file .Is that the reason I am facing problem to redirect the intent the page ???any help is highly appreciated

this is my new_user_register.java file

```
 public class new_user_register extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        EditText name1;
        EditText email1;
        EditText usname1;
        EditText password1;
        Button register;
        ToastManager toastManager;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.new_user_register);
    
    
            name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
            email1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email1);
            usname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usname1);
            password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
            register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerr);
    
            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    String NAME = name1.getText().toString().trim();
                    String EMAIL = email1.getText().toString().trim();
                    String username = usname1.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password = password1.getText().toString().trim();
    
    
                    String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]{3,32}+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,32}+$";
    
    
                    boolean isAtLeastOneFieldNotEmpty = !NAME.isEmpty()
                            || !EMAIL.isEmpty()
                            || !username.isEmpty()
                            || !password.isEmpty();
    
                    toastManager = new ToastManager(new_user_register.this);
    
                    // You have 5 registration fields that users must fill up.
                    final int totalRegistrationField = 5;
    
                    // This will increase by 1 when a field is valid
                    int validRegistrationFieldCount = 0;
    
                    if (isAtLeastOneFieldNotEmpty) {
                        // NAME VALIDATION
                        if (NAME.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER NAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((NAME.length() > 3) && (NAME.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("NAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 3-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!NAME.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ONLY ALPHABETS ALLOWED", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                        }
    
                        // EMAIL VALIDATION
                        if (EMAIL.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER EMAIL-ID", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(EMAIL.matches(emailPattern))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID EMAIL", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                        }
    
    
                        // USERNAME VALIDATION
                        if (username.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                        }
    
                        // PASSWORD VALIDATION
                        if (password.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else {
                            ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
    
                    if (validRegistrationFieldCount != totalRegistrationField) {
                        // Finally show all toast all screen
                        toastManager.show();
                    } else {
    
    
                        Intent i = new Intent(new_user_register.this, bottom_nav.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            });
    
        }
    }
```

this is my new_user_register.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".loginpage"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="216dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="561dp"
            android:text="NEW USER REGISTRATION"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="207dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_foreground"
            android:text="USERNAME"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="256dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="501dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_foreground"
            android:text="NAME"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name1"
            android:layout_width="291dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="434dp"
            android:hint="ENTER NAME" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="229dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="386dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_foreground"
            android:text="EMAIL ID"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email1"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="87dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="326dp"
            android:hint="ENTER EMAIL ID" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usname1"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
            android:hint="ENTER USERNAME" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t3"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_foreground"
            android:text="PASSWORD"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password1"
            android:layout_width="286dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
            android:hint="ENTER PASSWORD" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="525dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imaagee" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="408dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="292dp"
            android:src="@drawable/iimagee" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imagee" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imageee" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes .My validations are correct..It is not causing any problem

Comment: Just my page is not getting intended

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(new_user_register.this, bottom_nav.class);
                        startActivity(i);

Comment: I am intenting the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below condition will always true. Look at

```
if (validRegistrationFieldCount != totalRegistrationField)
```

Thats why code inside `else` part is not executing and `startActivity(i)` is never called.

Problem is actually there are 4 input fields namely **NAME**, **EMIAL**, **USER NAME** and **PASSWORD**, but you have set **totalRegistrationField = 5**.

Solution: Just reset variable like

`final int totalRegistrationField = 4;`